# Why is the rcsfreeze command missing from an installation of RCS?

Tags: version-control, rcs

I have installed [RCS](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/) in Ubuntu 20.04 using `sudo apt-get install rcs`. The usual RCS commands such as `ci`, `co`, `rlog`, `rcsdiff`, `rcsclean`, etc. work as expected. However, `rcsfreeze` is missing. When I try to run `rcsfreeze`, I get `rcsfreeze: command not found`. Why is it missing? How do I get the `rcsfreeze` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> rcsfreeze: command not found

Many other Linux distributions have /usr/bin/rcsfreeze, but not Debian, Ubuntu https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rcs : » The distribution also includes the program rcsfreeze, which is not normally installed «

Ubuntu 20.04: Creating and installing `rcsfreeze` → rcs-5.9.4 https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/rcs/rcs-5.9.4.tar.xz

```
tar xvf rcs-5.9.4.tar.xz
cd rcs-5.9.4/
./configure --prefix=/usr
.
   ## rcsfreeze is a script, created at configure time from rcsfreeze.sh: 
                "config.status: creating src/rcsfreeze"
   ## install rcsfreeze:
sudo install -m 755 src/rcsfreeze /usr/bin
```

Comment: Does this mean that I have to compile and install from source just to be able to use `rcsfreeze`?

Comment: No. As the text says : `./configure` and install one file `sudo install -m 755 src/rcsfreeze /usr/bin` . ........ ( "compile" is when you run 'make', which you shouldn't do: No 'make' , no 'make install' ! )

Comment: How does this differ from using the `rcsfreeze.pl` script provided by the [Purdue RCS Homepage](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/RCShome/)?